# Save base api URI to window object

Tags: window, websecurity

As a requirement, we need to dynamically change the baseApiURI for different environments *on runtime*. Our current idea is to define a global variable and add it to `window`, e.g.:

```
window.baseApiURI = <someURI>
```

We currently cant think of any exposure for a XSS vulnerability (but you never know). But we still have the feeling that this way is not sufficiently safe.

What are scenarios, where someone could somehow overwrite this `window.baseApiURI` and therefore send data to misguided server? Would it help to freeze the object, or is there any way to only freeze this certain property?